# Flux change ribbon theory

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

In Griffiths electrodynamics, 7.31

It is said that for a loop moving with some velocity through a magnetic field,  the change in flux from time T to T+dt

Is the flux through the ribbon connecting the bounds of the surface.

$D\phi =  \phi(t+dt) - \phi(t) = \phi$(ribbon) =$ \int B \cdot da$ ribbon

Now mathematically how would I prove thus as this in in my head intuitively makes sense for uniform fields, but mathematically I don't know how to prove this

But for non uniform fields  B pointing in the K direction, increasing e.g linearly, if I were to have a loop move in this direction, the flux would increase but the ribbon flux would be zero hence paradox

Is this formula true? this is the only time I've ever seen it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's Figure 7.13 of Griffiths, which you provided in a screenshot:

[image]

So consider the boundary of the surface at time $t + dt$.  We can imagine two surfaces spanning this boundary:

- The surface at its later position, at time $t + dt$.  The flux through this surface would be $\phi(t + dt)$.
- The surface at its initial position, at time $t$, plus the "ribbon".  The flux through this surface would be $\phi(t) + \phi(\text{ribbon})$.

But since $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$, the flux through these two surfaces is the same, and so $\phi(t + dt) = \phi(t) + \phi(\text{ribbon})$.  This is equivalent to the desired result.

Your proposed counterexample of a magnetic field "pointing in the $K$ direction increasing linearly" would have $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} \neq 0$, and so would not be a valid magnetic field.

Comment: thanks for reminding me to use the divergence of B, But I would like to add, I'm sure sure if you already thought of this, but the correct way to show  it is $ 0 = \phi(t + dt) + \phi(\text{ribbon})  +(-\phi(t))$ as the sum of the fluxes are zero but$ \phi(t)$ flux' orientation needs to be flipped. which is saying the same thing as setting each surface to be equal as "flux in equals flux out" but I think the way I showed it, is a direct application of gauss law as DA on the closed surface is in the opposite direction to the original DA, Which actually means the formula is wrong in the book .

Comment: change in flux according to mine and your formula is-flux( ribbon) but the book takes it to be positive, any idea why?

Comment: @jensenpaull:  My guess is that Griffiths defined the normal vector on the ribbon to be pointing "inward" rather than "outward", but I don't have a copy in front of me to be sure.

Comment: nope I have done the cross product and it's defined outward. even on the diagram its outward. and it's online :) page 296

Comment: Hmm, puzzling.  I'll have to look more carefully at it when I'm with my textbooks again, but that probably won't be until Monday.

Comment: thanks,  he also then uses this result to derive faradays law for motional emf, with this negative ( which is correct)

Comment: I've attached a picture of the problem below

Comment: @jensenpaull: Thanks.  I've corrected my answer to show how he arrived at the result he did (basically, I had inverted the roles of $t$ and $t + dt$  compared to the way Griffiths defined them.)

Comment: why is this new formula the correct one, the operation of setting them equaling eachother is saying "flux in = flux out" the way you have defined your new formula you have said that the "flux in" is phi(t+dt) and that flux out is phi(ribbon) + phi(t) (as dA ribbon is defined outwards)with the fact that ribbon flux is defined outwards means the dA element for phi(t) is also outwards. However via the right hand rule that even Griffiths mentioned, dl on his diagram goes counter clockwise meaning the DA element should point inwards, which contradicts his original formula

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131157/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-jensen-paull).